# Pass array of object properties to filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a custom angular filter that I'm trying to make more generic. The filter looks a collection of employees and filters down the list based on the number of months that have passed since they were hired. I'm trying to make the filter more generic so I can use it on other lists that have dates but will have a different property name (for example: filter invoices that have been created in the last xx months). How can I pass in the name of the property I want to filter on, or how do I pass in the collection of just the date property instead of the whole object?

html

```
<html  ng-app="dateFilterTest">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="filterController">
        <select ng-model="maxLookBack">
            <option value="6">6 Months</option>
            <option value="12" selected="selected">1 Year</option>
            <option value="24">2 Year</option>
            <option value="999">All</option>
        </select>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="person in people | DateAgeFilter:maxLookBack">{{person.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/dateFiltercontroller.js"></script>
</html>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('dateFilterTest', []);

app.filter('DateAgeFilter', function(){
    return function(items, maxage) {

        var minDate = new Date()
        minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth() - maxage);

        var result = [];
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
          if (items[i].hireDate.getTime() > minDate.getTime()) {
            result.push(items[i]);
          }
        }

        return result;
    };
});

app.controller('filterController', function($scope){
    $scope.people = [
        {'name': 'Person 1',
         'hireDate': new Date('Jun 1, 2013')},
        {'name': 'Person 2',
         'hireDate': new Date('Aug 1, 2012')},
        {'name': 'Person 3',
         'hireDate': new Date('May 1, 2011')},
        {'name': 'Person 4',
         'hireDate': new Date('Jun 1, 2012')},
        {'name': 'Person 5',
         'hireDate': new Date('Mar 1, 2014')},
        {'name': 'Person 6',
         'hireDate': new Date('Mar 1, 2014')},
    ];
});
```

plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/9zOWxJdMNg5zHz7qYf7c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the property name in as an additional parameter to the filter- like so (using an additional colon separator):

```
DateAgeFilter:maxLookBack:'hireDate'
```

Below is an example of changing your filter to make use of that, with 2 changes:

1) The additional parameter- I've called it `field` here.

2) In order to use the parameter to specify the property, we switch from dot notation to bracket notation- changing `items[i].hireDate.getTime()` into `items[i][field].getTime()`

```
app.filter('DateAgeFilter', function(){
  return function(items, maxage, field) {

    var minDate = new Date()
    minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth() - maxage);

    var result = [];
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i][field].getTime() > minDate.getTime()) {
        result.push(items[i]);
      }
    }

    return result;
  };
});
```

[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N88DlxEVOOkz3HYw3XMz?p=preview)